# Home network topology and approach

Tags: networking, routing, home-networking, vlan, wan

I'm hoping to get some advice on topology and approach to accomplish my goals using the hardware stack identified here (I don't mind adding/subtracting HW if needed). I know how to do some of this work and understand the concepts, but don't know the best way to tie it all together and am missing some key knowledge around VLANs and static routes. Thanks in advance!

**Network Hardware**

- Netgear Cable Modem - CM1200 Router
- Netgear Nighthawk X4S/R7800 - FW V1.0.2.68 (Router, WiFi, DHCP)
- Netgear Managed Switch - GS110TPP - FW V7.0.1.16
- Miscellaneous slower AC and N routers no longer in use

**Goals**

- Create 2 VLANs - (1) Home lab and (2) Other devices (PC/tablet/phone)
- Both VLANs will have access to the internet
- Allow a small number of selected external/WAN IP addresses (friends/coworkers/collaborators) traffic into VLAN1 - do not allow any of this external traffic into other VLANs
- Allow some (or all) VLAN2 anywhere on LAN to connect to VLAN1

**Environment**

- All IP addresses are currently on the same subnet: 192.168.142.0/24
- Mostly Linux (CentOS and Debian/Ubuntu), some MacOS and Windows 10
- DNSmasq provides DNS for all lab addresses for future VLAN1 (DNSmasq is used primarily to provide wildcard DNS for a Kubernetes project)
- Nighthawk/R7800 provides DHCP and select static IP addresses for future VLAN2